# Find first non-blank value in one column and return said value for all other matching values

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I have two columns in my table: `A` and `B`

```
     A       | B
1    John    | 
2    John    | Yes
3    Paul    |
4    John    |
```

I want to enter a formula in column `B` such that if I were to enter a NON-blank value in `B2` it would fill all matches of John in column `A` with that same values (i.e: Yes).

Seems like it's a match of `VLOOKUP` and `MATCH`, but I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for...

```
       A      |             B              |   Result
R1    John    | =IF(A1="John","Yes","No")  |    Yes
R2    John    | =IF(A2="John","Yes","No")  |    Yes
R3    Paul    | =IF(A3="John","Yes","No")  |    No
R4    John    | =IF(A4="John","Yes","No")  |    Yes
```

(EDIT)

You will have to use a VBA event handler then. Right click on your Sheet Name and click "View Code", then paste the following...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("B2").Value = "Yes" Or Range("B2").Value = "yes" Then

Set Rng = Range("B1")
Rng(1).Value = "Yes"
Rng(4).Value = "Yes"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: No. What i want is if i enter the String "Yes" in B2 then B1 and B4 should also populate with "Yes"

Comment: how would i have this VBA apply to every field in the column?

Comment: Simply add another range varient: "Rng(RowNumber, ColumnNumber)"

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answer if this helped, thanks.